# UIImagePickerController with Custom OverlayView Crash on iPod iOS5, iPhone4S iOS5

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using following coding to shoot a video, I'm facing a strange issue in this. Below coding are working perfectly fine with iPad iOS6, iPad iOS5, iPhone iOS6 devices but crashing on iPod iOS5, iPhone4S iOS5.

```
UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
                cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;


                // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures, or for
                // trimming movies. To instead show the controls, use YES.
                cameraUI.allowsEditing = YES;
                cameraUI.delegate = self.objVideoAnalysis;
                cameraUI.showsCameraControls = NO;
                cameraUI.navigationBarHidden = YES;
                cameraUI.toolbarHidden = YES;

                // Displays a control that allows the user to choose movie capture
                cameraUI.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
                cameraUI.cameraCaptureMode = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
                //cameraUI.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;


                //set Overlay View for recording
                VideoRecorderOverlayView *objOverlay = [[VideoRecorderOverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
                objOverlay.objVideoRecorder = cameraUI;
                cameraUI.cameraOverlayView = objOverlay;
                [objOverlay release];

                [self presentModalViewController:cameraUI animated: YES];
```

Thanks in advance,
Ganesh.

Comment: Please post the exception you're encountering.

Comment: It's stop on a thread with badaccess exception.

Comment: I am also having the same issue. Can you please help me?